# Motivation behind the weak formulation of the Navier-Stokes equation

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, fluid-dynamics

Let

- $T>0$
- $d\in\mathbb N$
- $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be bounded and open and $\partial\Omega$ be Lipschitz
- $Q:=(0,T)\times\Omega$

I'm reading *Navier-Stokes Equations: Theory and Numerical Analysis* by *Roger Temam*. [The author states](https://books.google.de/books?id=CKYJBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA190&lpg=PA190&dq=%22let+us+assume+that%22+%22are+classical+solutions+of%22+%22obviously%22+%22one+can+check+easily%22&source=bl&ots=0pxJXWiWNg&sig=qtNOku3DL43MJ8Q8-3yixV0qYkI&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiD2OnFgPPOAhUMDSwKHfw8AzUQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22let%20us%20assume%20that%22%20%22are%20classical%20solutions%20of%22%20%22obviously%22%20%22one%20can%20check%20easily%22&f=false) that if $u\in C^2(\overline Q,\mathbb R^d)$ is a classical solution of the Navier-Stokes equation, then it would be *obvious* that $$\tilde u(t):=u(t,\;\cdot\;)\;\;\;\text{for }t\in(0,T)$$ belongs to $L^2((0,T),V)$, where $V$ is a (special) closed subspace of $H_0^1(\Omega,\mathbb R^d)$.

Maybe it's cause [I don't understand the definition of $C^2(\overline Q,\mathbb R^d)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1912980/whats-the-definition-of-ck-overline-lambda-for-a-bounded-and-open-lambda), but [I don't even understand why $\tilde u$ takes values in $V$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1912297/if-u-in-c0-overline%ce%9b-t-%e2%84%9dd-cap-c1-2%ce%9b-t-%e2%84%9dd-then-0-t-to-h-01%ce%9b).

> So, how can we prove the claim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u$ is continuously differentiable on a bounded set, presumably required to zero on the boundary, by assumption, so it is obvious that $u$ is in $L^2$, its derivative is in $L^2$, and it is zero on the boundary.  That the divergence of $u$ is zero is a part of the NSE.  So $u(t)$ is in $V$ for all $t$.  The fact that it is in $L^2(0,T;V)$ can be found with some simple calculus.

$$u_t + (u\cdot \nabla) u -\Delta u+\nabla p=0 $$

$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\int |u|^2 \,dx + \int(u\cdot \nabla) u\cdot u\,dx +\int|\nabla u|^2dx=0 $$

Then integrating in time you get that $||\nabla u||_{L^2}$ is in $L^2(0,T)$.

Comment: The crucial part is $$\tilde u(t)\in V\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in(0,T)\;.\tag 1$$ If $\partial\Lambda$ is Lipschitz, then $$V=\left\{v\in H_0^1(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d):\nabla\cdot v=0\right\}\;.\tag 2$$ Since $$\nabla\cdot\tilde u(t)=0\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in(0,T)$$ (where $\nabla\cdot\tilde u(t)$ is the classical divergence), the only thing which isn't clear to me is that $$\tilde u(t)\in H_0^1(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in(0,T)\;.\tag 3$$ In light of [an other discussion](http://tinyurl.com/z3gv4el), it's not obvious to me that $(3)$ holds.

Comment: It's $C^2$ on a bounded domain.  The derivative is bounded, so it's square integrable.

Comment: Did you take a look at the comments under the [answer to the linked question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1912316/47771)? Why do you think that the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial u(t,\;\cdot\;)}{\partial x_i}$ are bounded? By definition, the $\frac{\partial u(t,\;\cdot\;)}{\partial x_i}$ are continuous in $\Lambda$ and I don't see that the other properties of $u$ yield that the $\frac{\partial u(t,\;\cdot\;)}{\partial x_i}$ can be continuously extended to $\overline\Lambda$ (which is a compact set and I assume that you're using that a continuous function is bounded on a compact set).

Comment: I assume $C^2(\bar{Q})$ means the 2nd partial derivatives are continuous on $\bar{Q}$.

Comment: Now, it's still not clear why $\tilde u(t)\in H_{\color{red}0}^1(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$. See [my other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1915365/if-u-in-c1-omega-with-left-u-right-partial-lambda-0-then-h-01-la).

Comment: Of course, $u$ is only 0 on the boundary if it is assumed so.  The boundary conditions are a part of the PDE that $u$ is assumed to satisfy.

Comment: Why do we need to consider the calculation in your answer? In light of our discussion, shouldn't $u,\nabla u\in L^2$ simply follow from boundedness of $u,\nabla u$ in $\Lambda$?

Comment: Still interested in an answer to the last question.

Comment: yup you're right